# How can I remove the warning "Cannot match several associated values at once"

Tags: ios, swift, tuples, xctest

I have a helper method in my unit tests:

```swift
  func expect(_ sut: CompanyStore, toRetrieve expectedResult: RetrieveCacheResult, when action: @escaping (() -> Void), file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    let exp = expectation(description: "await completion")

    sut.retrieve { retrievedResult in
      switch (expectedResult, retrievedResult) {
      case (.empty, .empty), (.failure, .failure):
        break
      case let (.found(retrieved), .found(expected)):
        XCTAssertEqual(retrieved.item, expected.item, file: file, line: line)
        XCTAssertEqual(retrieved.timestamp, expected.timestamp, file: file, line: line)

      default:
        XCTFail("Expected to retrieve \(expectedResult), got \(retrievedResult) instead", file: file, line: line)
      }

      exp.fulfill()
    }
    action()
    wait(for: [exp], timeout: 1.0)
  }
```

It allows me to create tests such as:

```swift
  func test_retrieve_delivers_empty_on_empty_cache() {
    let sut = makeSUT()
    expect(sut, toRetrieve: .empty, when: {
      // some action to perform
    })
  }
```

Since upgrading to Swift 5.1 I am getting the following warning:

> Cannot match several associated values at once, implicitly tupling the
>   associated values and trying to match that instead

On the following line

```
 case let (.found(retrieved), .found(expected)):
```

These values are a tuple `(item: LocalCompany, timestamp: Date)`

I haven't been able to work out how to clear this warning.

Edit:

`.found` is an enum:

```swift
public enum RetrieveCacheResult {
  case empty
  case found(item: LocalCompany, timestamp: Date)
  case failure(Error)
}
```

Comment: How about `case (.found(let retrieved), .found(let expected))`? [Typed directly, haven't actually tried it.]

Comment: Hey Matt, I'd tried that and it still shows the warning I'm afraid

Comment: Okay, if you want me to actually work on the problem, can you reveal what the declaration of this type is? What is `.found`?

Comment: `found` returns a tuple, `(item: LocalCompany, timestamp: Date)`. `LocalCompany` contains `item` and `timestamp` which are `String` and Date` types.

Comment: Yes but the dot? `.found` implies this is a case of some enum? Would you mind, please, pretty please, just showing the declaration of that enum? Would you please make an effort to allow me to reproduce the issue? Don't make me _guess_ what's going on the rest of the code; _show_ the rest of the code.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I misunderstood what you had asked for. I've updated the question with that enum also. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so you can do it if you say `case let (.found(whatitem, whattime), .found(item: whatitem2, timestamp: whattime2))` as Jessy says.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Redefine the associated value to be a tuple.

```swift
case found( (item: Int, timestamp: Bool) )
```

2. Extract all the members individually.

```swift
case let (
  .found(retrievedItem, retrievedTimestamp),
  .found(expectedItem, expectedTimestamp)
):
```

Comment: I enjoy the masterful use of emoji here 

Answer (score 1):

1. Example you have this : case todo(shoppingCount: Int, eating: Bool)
2. In usage:

---

```
           case .todo(let shoppingCount, _):
               print("Shopping count = ", shoppingCount)
```

---

```
           case .todo(_, let eating):
               print("Eating = ", eating)
```